# Which code would you prefer and why? Program to swap values using pointers

Tags: c

This is a program to swap two numbers using pointers.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void swap(int *x, int *y){
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp; 
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int *a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *b = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a =1;
    *b =2;
    printf("Nos are: %i %i\n", *a, *b);
    swap(a,b);
    printf("Swapped: %i %i\n", *a, *b);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Would you prefer this or,

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void swap(int *x, int *y){
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp; 
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a= 1;
    int b= 2;
    printf("Nos are: %i %i\n", a, b);
    swap(&a,&b);
    printf("Swapped: %i %i\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Which one is better in terms of programming standards? or which one would you prefer? (pls give some theoretical explanation as well)
**Output for both the codes are same i.e it swaps and returns 2 1**

Comment: [codereview.se] would probably be a better place for this question.

Comment: you have to `free` the memory in first case

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure the folks in Code Review would thank you for such a recommendation.

Comment: @AdrianMole OK, a better way to say it would be that if it belongs on any SE, it would be CR. But read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would
prefer first case if I am swapping some heavy data, lets say some `struct x`, so we pass address of `struct` which is a fixed size depends on system.

prefer second case for normal data like `int` or `char` etc..
There is **no need** to allocate memory and free.

Comment: dereference will work as struct assignments copy whole struct or union. No memcpy needed

Comment: @0___________ what if `struct` has pointers?

Comment: It does not matter you do not swap objects referenced by the pointers only the structs itself. https://godbolt.org/z/afGabW

Comment: @0___________, right i got it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not prefer `swap` function using pointers.
This task is best done by the macros:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(a,b,type) do{type c__c__c; c__c__c = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = c__c__c;}while(0)

struct s
{
    int a;
    char x[100];
    double w[100];
};

int main()
{

    double a = 5.0, b = 6.0;
    int c = 5, d = 6;
    struct s x = {.a = 1},y = {.a = 2};

    SWAP(a, b, double);
    SWAP(c, d, int);
    SWAP(x, y, struct s);


    printf("%f %f\n", a, b);
    printf("%d, %d\n", c, d);
    printf("%d, %d\n", x.a, y.a);
    return 0;
}
```

and the code will every efficient. You also do not have to write dozens of functions for every type.

Of course you can write "generic" swap function

```
void *swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char temp[size];

    memcpy(temp, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, temp, size);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Why DV?  sdfsdfds\